# SQL Pivot/unpivot Column Names and corresponding values

Tags: sql, pivot

I currently have a query that returns one row of data.  I would like to pivot the last 4 or 5 into one column with corresponding values next to them.

[image: See sample image]

Comment: What RDBMS is this?

Comment: Ritesh, I get column name was not specified for column error.  I am using MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 0):

USE UNION

```
        SELECT peojectID,level_type,'LABOR' as Cost_Type,LABOR as Cost From Table UNION
        SELECT peojectID,level_type,'TRAVEL' as Cost_Type,TRAVEL as Cost From Table UNION
        SELECT peojectID,level_type,'MATERIAL' as Cost_Type,MATERIAL as Cost From Table UNION 
        SELECT peojectID,level_type,'ODCs' as Cost_Type,ODCs as Cost From Table UNION 
        SELECT peojectID,level_type,'FEE' as Cost_Type,FEE as Cost From Table 
        OEDER BY peojectID,level_type
```

Answer (score 0):

If Are you using MSSQL THEN try this one

```
   SELECT peojectID,level_type, Cost_type,Cost  
    FROM   
       (SELECT peojectID,level_type, LABOR, TRAVEL, MATERIAL, ODCs, FEE 
       FROM Table) p  
    UNPIVOT  
       (Cost  FOR Cost_type IN   
          (LABOR, TRAVEL, MATERIAL, ODCs, FEE )  
    )AS unpvt;
```